# C++ Error -- "cannot convert 'char (*)[3]' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char rLeft(char*, int, int)' rLeft(cI,4,3);"

Tags: c++, arrays

i am trying to create a program that will act as a rubik's cube. I created multi-dimensional arrays to act as a row for the rubik's cube (4*3).

I'm trying to create a function that will rotate one of the arrays the the left switching [3][0] to [2][0] and [2][0] to [1][0]...etc, and I'm getting this error and need help fixing it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char rLeft(char* const rArray,int rows,int colms);

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Left,~~~~~~~~Center,~~~~~~~~Right,~~~~~~~~Back~~~~~~~// 

    char rI [4][3] = {{'r','r','r'},{'b','b','b'},{'o','o','o'},{'g','g','g'}};
   char rII [4][3] = {{'r','r','r'},{'b','b','b'},{'o','o','o'},{'g','g','g'}};
  char rIII [4][3] = {{'r','r','r'},{'b','b','b'},{'o','o','o'},{'g','g','g'}};

    char cI [4][3] = {{'w','w','w'},{'r','r','r'},{'y','y','y'},{'o','o','o'}};
   char cII [4][3] = {{'w','w','w'},{'r','r','r'},{'y','y','y'},{'o','o','o'}};
  char cIII [4][3] = {{'w','w','w'},{'r','r','r'},{'y','y','y'},{'o','o','o'}};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" <<endl;
    rLeft(rI,4,3);
    return 0;
}            

char rLeft(int rArray[4][3], int rows, int colms);
{
    rows = 0;
    colms = 0;

    for (i = 0, i < rows, i++)
    {
        for (ii = 0, ii < colms, ii++)
        {
            if (rows != 3)
            {
                rArray[rows][colms] = rArray[rows+1][colms]
                return rArray[row][colms];
            }
            else 
            {
                rArray[rows][colms] = rArray[0][colms]
                return rArray[row][colms];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char rLeft(char* const rArray,int rows,int colms);` is not same as `char rLeft(int rArray[4][3], int rows, int colms)`

Answer (score -1):

Well, clearly your first declaration of the function differs from the second. Make then identical:

```
char rLeft(int rArray[4][3], int rows, int colms);
```

You also need to remove the semicolon from the function definition:

```
char rLeft(int rArray[4][3], int rows, int colms)
//                                                ^^^^^ (no semicolon)
{
    // ...
```